# r lapply by id variable

Tags: r, lapply

I have two data frames, DFA with dates and id, and other DFB with id, and two columns of dates date0, date1.
I want a function to search the dates in DFA in DFB and create a list with 1 if the date is in de range and 0 if is not.
After severals trials, I have this function:

```
completa_roles <- function(x, y, z) {
for(i in 1: length(y)){ 
    if ((x >= y[i] & x <= z[i])==TRUE) {
      m[i] <- 1
      } else {
      m[i] <- 0 
      }
    }
 return(m)
}

lapply(x, FUN=completa_roles, y=DFB$date0, z=DFB$date1)
```

This work ok for one id, but I can't split the function by an id variable, I tried by, tapply and dlply. Help will be apreciated.
Example:

```
DFA <- data.frame(id= c(3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5), x=c("2007-07-01", "2007-08-01", "2007-09-01",
                                          "2007-10-01", "2007-11-01", "2007-12-01", 
                                          "2010-06-01", "2009-06-01", "2008-06-01"),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DFB <- data.frame(id=c(3,3,3,3,5,5), date0=c("2010-01-01", "2008-02-20", "2007-04-02",
               "2012-09-01", "2000-06-01", "2004-06-01"), date1=c("2015-06-30", "2009-12-31", "2012-08-31",
               "2015-06-30", "2002-06-01", "2008-06-01"),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DFA$x <- as.Date(DFA$x, origin = "1970-01-01")
DFB$date0 <- as.Date(DFB$date0, origin = "1970-01-01")
DFB$date1 <- as.Date(DFB$date1, origin = "1970-01-01")

m <- list()
completa_roles <- function(x, y, z) {
for(i in 1: length(y)){ 
if ((x >= y[i] & x <= z[i])==TRUE) {
  m[i] <- 1
} else {
  m[i] <- 0 
 }
 }
return(m)
}

x <- DFA$x
res <- lapply(x, FUN=completa_roles, y= DFB$date0, z= DFB$date1)
```

Comment: Please consider to provide reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks, I add an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, a perhaps syntactically cleaner way to do this is with the `dplyr` and `lubridate` libraries. You just want to do a join and check that x is within the interval:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

DFA %>%
  left_join(DFB) %>%
  mutate(in_range = x %within% interval(date0, date1),
         in_range = as.numeric(in_range))
```

Comment: Exactly what i need! Thanks, i've never worked with this packages before